# Stepper motor stalls at low frequencies. Why?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, h-bridge, gate-driving

I picked up a Howard Industries 1-19-4200 (5 wire) stepper and have been driving it on my testbench with a PIC18F2550 and L293D. I recently added a potentiometer to an analog pin of the PIC for speed control but have been running into serious problems trying to rotate at speeds above 120 rpm. The PIC and L293 will gladly generate signals into the kHz range and on the scope the waveforms are clean with no sagging or distortion on the supply phases to the motor. I'm also well underneath my regulator current limits. Above about 120 rpm though, the motor rumbles and just halts. It makes that characteristic synth sound at high frequencies, just no movement. I'm driving it with half stepping and I'm planning on going to microstepping once I fix this.

What am I doing wrong that the motor is stalling at such low speeds?

Edit: Also worth mentioning that my current consumption for the whole circuit drops from 400mA at low speeds to 300mA when stalled.

Comment: If this is about stalling at _high_ step rates, why does the title say "stalls at _low_ frequencies"?

Comment: I think the OP expected a very high swithing frequency and very high speed. For him, 120 rpm is very low speed. Thus switching frequencies in the range of kHz is low frequencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stepper motors are not designed to work with high speeds. They are designed to have high torque and precision.

Stability and torque of stepper motors drops when increasing frequency because:

**Large inductance of motor windings**

At high frequency all coils have higher impedance. Due to that increased impedance current drops at high frequencies.

**Eddys currents** power disspation

Power disspation caused by eddys currents is proportional to square of frequency.

More: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current#Power_dissipation_of_eddy_currents

Normally stepper motors are driven with maximum of 400-1000 full steps per second. With microstepping its possible to get higher speeds with same stability.

120RPM on 3.6deg/step motor? Seriously? Thats pretty impressive.

**To get higher speeds you need motor with bigger steps, some gears/transmission or diffrent kind of motor.**

Comment: Ah jeez, I saw a few videos of steppers going into kRPMs and thought that was typical. This was an inexpensive salvaged motor.

Answer (score 3):

It's not unusual to use a motor rated at (say) 0.9 ohms and 3A (2.7V) on a 24V supply using a "chopper" driver (the driver monitors the current thorough the coil and goes into a PWM mode when the ~3A current is exceeded, so the motor does not burn out).

The advantage of this is that the 3A current (and commensurate rotor torque) is reached much faster with the higher voltage. The current, starting from t=0 and i=0, is:

i(t) = \$\frac{V}{R}(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}})\$, where \$\tau = \frac{R}{L}\$

Unfortunately, your motor seems to be rated at 12V, even so there is some latitude for increasing the drive voltage. You do need a "chopper" type driver (or a high power-wasting series resistor) to keep the motor coils from overheating when they are not being driven at high speed.